# In UWP, when using a combobox inside a listview datatemplate, selectedItem is lost

Tags: listview, combobox, uwp, itemtemplate

There have been several similar questions asked, but I couldn't find anything that looked to be exactly the same as what I'm experiencing.

I've got a `ComboBox` inside a `DataTemplate` for a `ListView`. The `ComboBox` has the correct bindings to the `ItemsSource` as well as the `SelectedItem`. The pattern I'm using is the same pattern I use throughout the application without any problems.

For whatever reason though, the selected item is getting nulled out somewhere along the way.  I've put breakpoints inside the selected item and I can see that it is being properly set during the lists construction. Then, the selected item is being set again to `null` while the control is being rendered (at least that's the way it appears). When I look at the call stack at the point it's being set to `null`, the stack only shows the line I'm on `[External Code]`.

For reference, here is what the current code looks like:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Vm.ListVms, Mode=OneWay}" 
          SelectedItem="{x:Bind Vm.SelectedListVm, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource GenericConverter}}">

<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="ListItemVm">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <ComboBox 
                   ItemsSource="{x:Bind ComboBoxTypes, Mode=OneWay}"
                   SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedComboBoxType, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource GenericConverter}}"
                   DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
         </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The `ComboBoxTypes` is an `ObservableCollection`.
`SelectedComboBoxType` is set by referencing a row from the `RaceTypes`.

Again, as I mentioned above, this pattern that seems to work everywhere else in the application, but not inside a `ListView`.

Here is a sample of what the code looks like that I'm using to populate the list items and the combo boxes.  It's not actual code, because I can't provide the actual code.  It is close enough though that it illustrate the steps being taken.

```
        vm.ListVms.Clear();
        foreach (var unit in source.ListItems)
        {
            var listVm = new ListVm();
            listVm.ComboBoxTypes.Add();
            listVm.ComboBoxTypes.Add();
            listVm.ComboBoxTypes.Add();
            listVm.ComboBoxTypes.Add();
            listVm.SelectedComboBoxType = listVm.ComboBoxTypes.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == (int) unit.ComboBoxType);
            vm.ListVms.Add(listVm);
        }
```

Comment: You write that you use `RaceTypes` and `SelectedRaceType`, but I don't see that anywhere in the XAML, is that a typo? And could you please post your code-behind as well?

Comment: I suspect the problem will be in code, likely in the order the selection is set.

Comment: Sorry, I was changing some of the text to take out any of the business code.  I forgot to change the comment part to match the code part.  I'll fix that now.

Comment: I've updated the information to add some details about how the lists are being populated.

Comment: I've got a bit more detail to add here ... when the data is being loaded for the first time when the page is being initialized, it populates and selects the combobox entries correctly.  However, when I switch from one item to another, and reload the list for the newly selected item, the behavior I've described above occurs.

Comment: More details ... it would appear that the problem is coming from the primary list object being cleared before getting repopulated from the new item being displayed.  If I bypass the ListItems.Clear(), I will end up with duplicated rows in my list (as expected), but all of the ComboBoxes are being properly filled and the SelectedItem is being correctly set.

Comment: I would like to know where does the `unitVm` come from? I would bet the reason is that it contains some "old reference", and because the new items are new instances, it cannot select them. Why don't you do `listVm.FirstOrDefault` instead of `unitVm.listVm.FirstOrDefault` ?

Comment: I made a mistake in my simulated code.  It's been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a couple of workable answers from the Microsoft Developer Network, so I thought I would share them here for anybody who has run into this same problem.

**Option 1**
Put in a test on the setter to bypass updating the backing field if the value is null.

This is a hack to me, but it works perfectly.

```
public ComboboxItemVm SelectedComboBoxType
{
    get { return selectedType; }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("null!");
            return;
        }
        if (value != selectedType)
        {
            selectedType = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedComboBoxType"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2**
Change the binding on the SelectedItem from x:Bind to Binding.

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ComboBoxTypes, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboBoxType, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource GenericConverter}}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

It's disappointing that the solution is to use an older coding style, but it also fixes the issue without having to add an extra null-test-bypass option in the code.

[Here is a link to the original answer provided to me](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ea26230-ab89-4eb8-975c-f06373391a85/in-uwp-when-using-a-combobox-inside-a-listview-datatemplate-selecteditem-is-lost?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: I had the same issue when adding and removing an element multiple times from the ListView ItemSource. I'm using Microsoft.UI.Xaml v2.5 and MVVM Light. Option 2 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you reverse the order in which you select an item in the code-behind. Consider the following two options:

**Option 1**

```
SelectedComboBoxType = items[0];
ComboBoxTypes = items;
```

**Option 2**

```
ComboBoxTypes = items;
SelectedComboBoxType = items[0];
```

In **Option 1** you first set the selected item which causes change notification which is immediately handled by the control. The control is however not yet bound to `items` and therefore will not set `SelectedItem` to your selection but will in contrast cause an update back to `SelectedComboBoxType` with the previously selected value.

Basically this means that you always can select only *after* the value you want to select is already bound to the control. **Option 2** should solve your problem.

Comment: No, I can guarantee this is not the issue.  The list item is created.  The combo box list is set up and the selected item is set, all in that order.